# What does this sed command do? How to change it?

Tags: sed, html

I do not understand what does this command do:

```
 grep '<span id="geodata" class="geo">[-0-9.]*; [-0-9.]*</span>' -R articles/ --only-matching | sed 's@articles//@@' | sed 's@:<span id=.geodata. class=.geo.>@ @' | sed 's@; @ @' | sed 's@</span>@@' | sort -u -b -k1 > geocodes_from_html.txt
```

Some background: I'm processing wiki articles, I have a folder ("articles") full of them. The processing script was written years ago when the geo information about a place used to like that:

```
   <span id="geodata" class="geo">[-0-9.]*; [-0-9.]*</span>
```

Now it looks like that:

```
  <abbr class="latitude">[-0-9.]*</abbr><abbr class="longitude">[-0-9.]*</abbr>
```

What changes do I need to make to make the command work?

Comment: That code is a lousy way to extract the two coordinates from that html element... Instead of changing it you should use tools designed for this job...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided `grep` command searches for the string `<span [...]</span>` in any file, which is in the directory `articles`. The following `sed` commands are replacing several strings.

For example `sed s@articles/@@` (with **one slash /** only) can be read as: `sed search@this_string@replace_with_this@`; the string `articles/` will be replaced by nothing. Instead of piping from one `sed` to the next, you can combine all scripts to one with the same result.

If you do not want to use any other commands to extract the coordinates, you could use:

```
grep '<abbr class="latitude">[-0-9.]*</abbr><abbr class="longitude">[-0-9.]*</abbr>' -R articles --only-matching | sed 's@articles/@@;s@:<abbr class="latitude">@ @;s@<abbr class="longitude">@ @;s@</abbr>@@g' | sort -u -b -k1 >geocodes_from_html.txt
```